Differences between the many words for being "devoted to" something
Despite its length, this least is by no means exhaustive for describing the basic action of "devoting oneself", but I tried to gather words that I feel can be used very similarly. My criteria was "can you use it for devoting to studies/work/a position/a person?".
I will try to add my present understanding here:

打ち込む
Perhaps the most general for expressing "devotion" to something, as I see it used for studies, work, relationships, and political positions.
専念する/専心する
My understanding is that the only way these words differ is that 専念する can be used for focusing on "recuperating" from illness, with the common thread between the two being used for "devoting one's mind" to something.
傾倒する
Has a flavor of admiration for the thing you have gotten into rather than pure concentration, as it also has a meaning of "to be an ardent admirer of".
傾ける/傾注する
I'm guessing this is just a wago/kango difference between these words, but in any case they both take を marking nouns like 力 or 精神, and you mark work or studies with に. There are many other words/phrase like this like the expression ～に心血を注ぐ, but these two seemed to most explicitly be used for "devotion".
明け暮れる
Seems to be used like 打ち込む but with a potentially more negative nuance considering it's like doing something "from dawn to dusk". Perhaps a little more conversational I'm guessing.
精進する
Outside of it's (I'm guessing) original connotations of Buddhist asceticism and adherence to a vegetarian diet (精進料理), it seems like a real "devotion" kind of devotion. Like for the bettering of one's life even if it's still also used with studies, etc.
徹する
I want to say this word is mainly used for like a position or activity that is significant (信仰に徹する), but I also found usages like this one:


自分もそれを心得ていて、大体の場合、話すより聞く事に徹していたと思います。

...where it seems to more mean something like "prioritize" I guess?

献身する
Perhaps more commonly used as 献身的, definitely has the connotation of "sacrificing" your self for someone/something, as in this example:


科学に献身した人　a person dedicated to science; a votary of science


尽くす/尽力する
Again seems to just be wago/kango difference, also seems to have the nuance of sacrifice or "using everything up" for something/someone, maybe the idea is you are giving up more of your "reserves" and in 献身する you are giving up "the whole" of yourself.
勤しむ
This seems to be used just like 打ち込む but also may contain the nuance that the work in question is strenuous/difficult, it also seems to be not used for devoting yourself to a person, only studies/training/work.
事とする
Devotion, but also carries the idea that you firmly believe in the thing in question, and that you are shouldering an important duty by devoting yourself to the marked noun, like in this example:


天下国家を事として妻子をかえりみない


かかりきり
I think this word has more of a negative nuance that the marked noun is taking up all of your time, so you have less time to spend with other things/people. Also used with だ and not する.

Even if I have a decent understanding of these words, from these potential nuances alone I don't feel confident applying them to the appropriate situations yet. Most of these seem to be able to be used like 「仕事に～する」or a similar form, so I'm unsure what situations you would differentiate them practically and what kind of impression they give (how much effort, are you losing something, do you enjoy it, is it for a cause, etc).

I'm afraid to say this list includes quite a few phrases almost unrelated to devotion, while it doesn't have 夢中, 没頭, 熱中, and so on. Also, your understanding of some of the words seems not quite correct.

専念する: The core meaning is "to focus exclusively on one task and not to do others". 『経理の会社をやめて音楽の仕事に専念することにする』『副業をせず本来の自分の業務に専念しなさい』『雑用が多くて研究に専念できない』 専心する is probably synonymous to 専念, but is fairly uncommon today.
傾倒する: This means having an extreme and long-term interest in a niche artistic style, academic topic, ideology, social policy, religion, etc. 傾倒 can be admirable if they succeed socially in that field, but otherwise, it's often seen negatively. Synonyms include 心酔 and 信奉. 『幼少時からラテン音楽に傾倒し18歳で有名になった』『カルト宗教に傾倒して財産を失った』『フェミニズムに傾倒しすぎるのは良くない』
明け暮れる: This means doing something all day long, every day. It may be used with an undesirable thing. 『仕事に明け暮れる生活のせいで、ニュースを見る暇もない』『小さいころはサッカーに明け暮れる毎日だった』
尽力する: This doesn't refer to spending time on personal interests, but rather making a significant contribution to the development of an organization, project, etc. 『先生は本学会の発展に尽力されました』『このイベントは〇〇さんの尽力なしには成功しませんでした』
献身する: Like 尽力, but has a stronger sense of self-sacrifice. This means the effort is solely for the benefit for others.
徹する: Means "to stubbornly stick to one thing/policy and refuse to do something else", but it's typically used with a short-term strategy. 『今は守りに徹するべきだ』『何を聞かれても沈黙に徹すること』
精進する: Means "to continuously train oneself in a disciplined manner". This typically involves spiritual/moral improvement or a master-apprentice relationship.
勤しむ: Conveys an image of diligently and routinely doing small tasks every day, rather than taking on challenging endeavors. 『日々昆虫の研究に勤しんでおります』『勉学に勤しむ大学生』
かかりきりになる: This basically means someone becomes overly occupied. 『トラブルの事後処理にかかりきりでメールの返事も寄こさない』『家族の介護にかかりきりになったせいで旅行に行けない』
事とする: I don't think it's commonly used in modern Japanese. If there's enough context, it may be understood like "to regard it as one's lifework" or something.

